# I am unable to get my new Angular Project up and running

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML looks this:

```
            <html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
                <head>
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    ******{{randomValue}}*******
                </body>
            </html>
```

My Javascript looks like this:

```
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
                'ui.bootstrap',
                'ngSanitize'
            ]);

            myApp.config(['$stateProvide', '$httpProvider', function config($stateProvider, $httpProvider) {

            }]);

            myApp.run(['$location', '$timeout', '$rootScope', function($location, $timeout, $rootScope) {

            }]);

            myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

                $scope.randomValue = "Hello World!";

            }]);
```

I am getting an angular error in the browser console that leads me to the [Angular Website](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=birchBoxApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.5%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.bootstrap%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.5%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.bootstrap%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A78%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A141)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A384%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A332%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A180)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A349%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:38:98%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:37:180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:37:349%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:37:180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:40:435)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js:19:381)

Comment: do you have ui.bootstrap installed?

Comment: Do you have ngSanitize referenced? 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

And you never added references for these dependencies below:
'angular-ui-router', 'angular-ui-bootstrap'


$stateProvide is missing 'r' $stateProvider

Comment: If you used the non-min version of Angular you get much more useful error messages in the console. This could help you/us pin down the problem.

Comment: You could improve your question by stating what the error message is as opposed to providing a link.

Comment: You are lack of some libraries in your HTML file.

Comment: Have you included your javascript file in html page?

Comment: actually it is best to put the example in a jsfiddle or plunker for other people to try and see.  I wonder if you remove the `config` and `run` lines will it run (to output the hello world).  Then you can try removing the controller lines and see if it error out... elimination and see

Comment: Check your app Injection, and insert scripts files in your Html.

Comment: You really need to find another tutorial about AngularJS. I can recommend you to watch the tutorial in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993297/Angular-Tutorial-Part-Introduction-to-Angular-js

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and for your help. I was able to get everything resolved. There were definitely a couple of issues. Primarily not importing all of the libraries. But then there was also the type caught by Syed. Thank you guys for the help.